# Vaadin Tree with JPAContainer

Tags: tree, vaadin

I have a problem to use the JPAContainer with tree.
after setting the data source and the tree:

```
jpaContainer.setParentProperty("parent");
tree = new Tree(null, jpaContainer);
tree.setImmediate(true);
tree.setSizeFull();
tree.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY);
tree.setItemCaptionPropertyId("description");
```

I try to add one entity:

```
jpaContainer.addEntity(entity);
```

This action triggers the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.JPAContainer.getContainerFilters()Ljava/util/Collection;
at com.vaadin.ui.Tree.containerItemSetChange(Tree.java:942)
```

The line of code that throws the error (belonging to Tree.containerItemSetChange method) is the following:

```
boolean hasFilters = !((Filterable) getContainerDataSource())
                        .getContainerFilters().isEmpty();
```

JPAContainer does not have the getContainerFilters() method, instead have the getFilters() method.

i'm using vaadin 7.1.7

it's a bug ? or is my error ??

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What version of JPAcontainer are you using?

Comment: the latest (it's the default configuration)

Comment: make sure you are really using jpacontainer 3.1. If I remember it right this was the error I had while using jpacontiner 3.0 with vaadin 7.1

Comment: The version that i have is 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT how i can see the last artifact ?

Comment: That depends on your tool chain (maven, ivy, eclipse) See Chapter 17 of the vaadin book about installing add-ons: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/addons.html

Comment: now work very well, thank you raffael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

When you use the maven command to build a new project with the latest version of vaadin (7.1.7 for example) you have in the pom the dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
<artifactId>jpacontainer-addon</artifactId>
<version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency downloads the jpaContainer 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT incompatible with vaadin 7.1.x.
We need to replace the dependency with this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
<artifactId>jpacontainer</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for support Raffael

Comment: You can chose your own answer as being the correct one (after some time threshold if I recall correctly). It does not necessarily have to be someone else's.